# Link an external CSS from within a application.sass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, css, sass

Using Rails 3.2.0 with haml and sass:
I Would like to link an external style sheet as in this command performed in the header

```
<link href="http://jeromeetienne.github.com/jquery-mobile-960/css/jquery-mobile-960.min.css" />
```

but I would to accomplish this when I make the call

```
= stylesheet_link_tag "application", :media => "all"
```

so in my application.sass (I make a habit of only using sass style sheets) I would like to say

```
//= link some external style sheet
```

Is this possible? and if so how would I go about doing so?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
@import "http://jeromeetienne.github.com/jquery-mobile-960/css/jquery-mobile-960.min.css"
```

Without `//-`